# VS2013 TFS Workspace Cannot Remap local folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

Had a TFS folder hive mapped to "C:\Projects (TFS online)\ProjNameHere" and discovered problems with Xamarin due to the space in the name.

So, I deleted my old (obsolete) "C:\Projects" folder, renamed "C:\Projects (TFS online)" to "C:\Projects" and went into VS Source Control explorer to modify the workspace mappings. I did this and it acted like it worked, but it still shows the old path atop Source Code Explorer "Local Path:" and it re-creates the old projects folder. It seems woefully confused which is right, because when I go to unmap or remap again it has the correct (new) folder path.

Did some googling and tried deleting all the TFS cache files I could find, but no help there.

Comment: I usually delete Workspaces and local files and then create a new Workspace instead of trying to Edit/Move stuff around.

Comment: Dave, I might use that workaround next time, but it sure would be nice if the functions of VS actually did what they are supposed to do, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project and select "Get Latest Version" from Source Control Explorer, this should get the local path updated to the new one.

If you have some change in local hasn't been checked in, you can add the solution to source control from Solution Explorer and check in the pending changes first and then get the latest version from Source Control.

Comment: That was the fix, thanks. Would you agree this is a "bug" in VS?